# query from the child to the great great grandfather list in ORACLE 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, parent-child, hierarchy, oracle12c

I need help with a SQL query.
I have this table:

```
ITEM     PARENT
1          NULL
2           1
3           2
4           2
5           3
6           5
7           5
8           4
9           8
10          1
11          10
12          10
13          8
```

Chosen an item, i'd need the following result:

Chosen item 9: family list: 8,4,2,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can resolve this by using `START WITH` and `CONNECT BY`

[Oracle documentation for Hierarchical Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

The SQL in your case would look like the following

```
SELECT item 
  FROM t START WITH item = 9 
CONNECT BY PRIOR parent = item
```

Comment: Thanks mcha, but i've already read this doc but i can't sort the problem out

Comment: @Madmartigan I added the SQL, I don't have Oracle to test, that is the reason I didn't write the query in the first place :)

Comment: select PARENT, ITEM 
    from table
    where PARENT is not null
    START WITH item = 9
    connect by prior PARENT = ITEM
    order by PARENT, ITEM

Comment: Incredible. This is the query I was using. I've just changed" ITEM = PARENT" to "PARENT = ITEM" and it works

Comment: you are welcome! basically you would use CONNECT BY PRIOR to retrieve child items, in your case you are doing the opposite, retrieving Parents of childs, that is why you need to connect with parent = item instead of item = parent

Answer (score 0):

Specifically `9`

```
SELECT parent
FROM yourtable 
WHERE item = 9
UNION ALL
SELECT parent
FROM yourtable 
WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
                FROM yourtable y2
                WHERE item = 9
                AND item = y2.item)
UNION ALL
SELECT parent
FROM yourtable 
WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
               FROM yourtable 
               WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
                              FROM yourtable y2
                              WHERE item = 9
                              AND item = y2.item))
UNION ALL
SELECT parent
FROM yourtable 
WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
               FROM yourtable 
               WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
                              FROM yourtable 
                              WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
                                             FROM yourtable y2
                                             WHERE item = 9
                                             AND item = y2.item)))
```

Using a parameter `@ITEM`

```
SELECT parent
FROM yourtable 
WHERE item = @ITEM
UNION ALL
SELECT parent
FROM yourtable 
WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
                FROM yourtable y2
                WHERE item = @ITEM
                AND item = y2.item)
UNION ALL
SELECT parent
FROM yourtable 
WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
               FROM yourtable 
               WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
                              FROM yourtable y2
                              WHERE item = @ITEM
                              AND item = y2.item))
UNION ALL
SELECT parent
FROM yourtable 
WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
               FROM yourtable 
               WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
                              FROM yourtable 
                              WHERE item IN (SELECT parent
                                             FROM yourtable y2
                                             WHERE item = @ITEM
                                             AND item = y2.item)))
```

OUTPUT

```
PARENT
8
4
2
1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97af9/11/0

Comment: Thanks Matt, the problem is that my real table is longer than the example one

Comment: How long? you could store the first statement as a variable and then load it for x amount of times (count(item)) or something or loop it until parent is nulll